# How do I use Facebook Login via Facebook App for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a little problem. I am sing Facebook's API to get users information. I am using the code that provide here: https://github.com/pedro1993/ios-howtos

In those examples, when somebody logs in with Facebook they are taken to the Facebook app, whereas when in my app, Facebook is opened in a UIWebView. How can I stop that from happening and use the Facebook app?

Here is an example:

[image]

Peter

Comment: Show your own code of how you're using the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this *official* tutorial instead https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0

**Update** Facebook SDK has several fallback behaviors to try before it falls back to in-app web view. You can debug it by setting breakpoints in corresponding places in code. From the look of it https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/296771f5ed7674fcbed9c31cf39bf9c8e4706403/src/Login/FBSession.m#L1039 seems like a good place to start.

Especially try to debug `-[FBSessionAppSwitchingLoginStategy tryPerformAuthorizeWithParams:session:logger:`.

Comment: The link I provided is all of there official tutorials. I just forked it on to my git account.